# I can't compile google test which telling linker input unused (macOS)

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, googletest, macos-high-sierra

I have downloaded the google test with below command.

`wget https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.zip`

and I run the following command to install the libraries to my macOS 10.13.5

`unzip release-1.8.0.zip
cd googletest-release-1.8.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install`

and i try to compile the test as below code with command `g++ -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread -o cpptest test.cpp`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(firstTest, abs)
{
   EXPECT_EQ(1, abs( -1 ));
   EXPECT_EQ(1, abs( 1 ));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     std::cout << "Running main() from testmain.cc\n";

     testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
     return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
 }
```

but i get below warnings

```
clang: warning: -lgtest: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-lin-argument]
clang: warning: -lgtest_main: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Does anyone can fix this problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g++ -c` is used to compile a source file to an object file. This stage does not link an executable, i.e. it does not use linker, thus linker flags `-lgtest -lgtest_main` are not used. If you want to compile an executable the proper compand will be without `-c`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread -o cpptest test.cpp
```

Note, I have removed not required use of `-stdlib`.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I have been able to compile the code.